# Quiero crear un nuevo proyecto en angular

Tags: nodejs, angular

Estoy creando un nuevo proecto en angularjs y cuando casi esta terminando me sale este error
"The Schematic workflow failed. See above"
La versiones con las que estoy trabajando son: Angular
CLI: 12.0.2
Node: 14.15.4
Package Manager: npm 7.14.0

A continuación muestro lo que escribi en mi terminal del VS
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te corrijo una cosa: no es un proyecto de AngularJS, si no Angular (a secas). Ademas, si es posible, adjunta el log que genero npm al ejecutar el script "ng".

Comment: Gracias por corregirme, estoy entrando en el mundo de angular y corro riesgos de cometer errores una vez mas gracias

Comment: Prueba ejecutando `npm cache clean` y luego reintenta crear el proyecto usando Angular CLI.